# Incorrect pointer count onInterceptTouchEvent

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I want my ViewPager to only slide when using a single finger. So I extended the class and implemented onInterceptTouchEvent like so:

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
{
    if(ev.getPointerCount() > 1)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

But getPointerCount() is always returning '1', no matter how many points are on the screen. I get the correct number when I override onTouchEvent, but when I do that a bug is preventing the pager from working at all ( http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=18990 ) by throwning an app-killing exception when you raised your first finger out of multitouch: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: pointerIndex out of range

How else can I go about this?

**EDIT:**

The pointer count issue remains, but I was able to work around the exception that gets thrown in onTouchEvent.

I was doing this when I got the exception:

```
if(ev.getPointerCount() == 1)
{
    return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
}
return false;
```

The problem is that that when you raise your first finger out of multitouch, the ViewPager's onTouchEvent ends up processing the ACTION_UP event without first processing ACTION_DOWN. So I came up with this fix, which avoids the exception and will end the ViewPager's move when you put down a second finger:

```
private boolean moving = false;
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent (MotionEvent ev)
{
    int action = ev.getAction();
    if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    {
        moving = true;
    }
    if(ev.getPointerCount() == 1)
    {
        if(moving)
        {
            return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
        }

        if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
        {
            moving = false;
        }
    }
    else if(ev.getPointerCount() > 1 && moving)
    {
        ev.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_UP);
        moving = false;
        return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: great solution, thanks! This really saved me a lot of work, I thought I tried about everything already, including the answer below here, which still causes the exception.

Answer (score 5):

Your onTouchEvent did not work for me. I will investigate why. But meanwhile I did another workaround. I dug into ViewPager code and found that you can do that instead:

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

    if (ev.getPointerCount() > 1){
        ev.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);
    }

    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);

}
```

getPointerCount() works ok for me though. With the above code ViewPager processes also the ACTION_DOWN step and the bug in it never occure.

Comment: This finally solved similar problems I was having but unfortunately I had to find it out the hard way because search didn't come up with your answer. I will write a little bit more in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

So I finally found out how to solve the same problem and kind of know why it happens in the first place. I solved the problem without extending ViewPager but instead just set on touch event listener like in the example:

```
viewPager.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        // TODO This breaks sometimes in compatibility library code, try to fix
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            currentFragment.view.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
            if (!currentFragment.view.whole && event.getPointerCount() > 1) {

                event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);

            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

So what you have to do is just set event as cancelled instead of consuming it. When you return true in onTouch method event is consumed and doesn't bubble up to the view pager so it stops scrolling. But when you handle multiple pointer events it cuts the event after second touch but first is still sent so a viewpager and touch handler tries to act on multi touch and breaks because there is no second element of the event for finger two.

I agree that this shouldn't happen and it's a bug in the support library reported here (I think it is the one)
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=18990
It was marked as resolved some time ago but still happens in the newest version of SupportLibrary V4